# Word (French origin?) for first shot of war?

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't seem to find this word. It defines the opening fire of a battle.

Comment: Might you be thinking of "coup de grace" which means the final shot of a battle?

Comment: no, i'm sorry :(

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for _opening salvo_?

Comment: yes! it's a salvo! If you post I can accept your answer.

Comment: not sure salvo is exclussively, and in one word 'opening shot'.

Comment: It's often preceded by 'opening', so I had a connotation. Should I edit the title to reflect its actual meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for ***opening salvo***, according to the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[salvo](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/salvo)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> 1. A simultaneous discharge of artillery or other guns in a battle.
>
>    *‘a deafening salvo of shots rang out’*
>    *‘another salvo crashed nearer to the German positions’*
>
>    1.1 A number of weapons released from one or more aircraft in quick succession.
>
>    1.2 A sudden, vigorous, or aggressive act or series of acts.
>
>    *‘the pardons provoked a salvo of accusations’*
>
> **Origin**
>
> Late 16th century (earlier as salve): from French salve, Italian salva ‘salutation’.

I didn't realize that it was from the French, to be honest, but there ya go.

Answer (score 0):

One answer could be "opening volley", that has a French root according to OED.